# How to use LINQ to query list of strings that do not contain substring entries from another list

Tags: c#, linq

```
string[] candidates = new string[] {
    "Luke_jedi", "Force_unknown", 
    "Vader_jedi" , "Emperor_human", "r2d2_robot"
};

string[] disregard = new string[] {"_robot", "_jedi"};

//find those that aren't jedi or robots.
var nonJedi = candidates.Where(c=>
              c.??? //likely using EndsWith() and Any()
              );
```

How would you implement this solution using LINQ to find all those that do not end with any of the disregards items?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var nonJedi = candidates.Where(c => !disregard.Any(d => c.EndsWith(d)));
```

Answer (score 0):

**The NOT IN clause in LINQ to SQL** 
http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx